# Why an implicit conversion does not throw a compile time error?

Tags: scala

The following statement in Scala throws a Runtime error:

```
val a = 10: Object

error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than Object
   val a = 10: Object
           ^
```

If the above-mentioned implicit conversion is not allowed in Scala, then why doesn't Scala throws the error at compile time?

Comment: What Scala version are you using? This does not compile on 2.12.10

Comment: @Tim - I am using Scala v2.12.2

Comment: When you see `error: ...` it's always a compile-time error, not runtime.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - Got it, but then why IntelliJ does not show a red line below the above code in a Scala Worksheet?

Comment: IntelliJ Scala plugin simply doesn't reliably show errors (and sometimes shows errors where there aren't any), though of course they try to fix such problems over time. Report this one on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ after checking it isn't reported already.

Comment: Sure @AlexeyRomanov, will do it.

Comment: Created a bug for it - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-17189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think this is a runtime error? It is not:

```
$ scalac impl.scala                                                                  
impl.scala:3: error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than Object
val a = 10: Object
        ^
one error found
```

Comment: Because the statement `val a = 10: Object` does not show any error in the Scala Worksheet.